# Codeigniter 4 Passing Array to view

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Fairly new to codeigniter and i just cant find the right way to load an array into a view.

for example lets say i have an array like

```
  $data = [
    'title' => 'my title,
    'desc' => 'my desc,
  ];
```

i can pass that to my view like

```
return view('myview',$data);
```

then simply echo it out in my view like

```
<h1><?= $title ?></h1>
<p><?= $desc ?></p>
```

That works fine. but now lets say i have another array like :

```
$moredata =[
   'more_data' => 'some more data',
   'even_more_data' => 'even more data',
];
```

if i try to add that to my data array like

```
$data[] = $moredata
```

when i try to access 'more_data' or 'even_more_data' in my view like

```
<?= $more_data ?>
```

i get a undefined variable error for $moredata. So how do i access the variables within that new array? am i declaring them properly?

also if i wanted to loop through the secondary array how do i do that. trying

```
<?php foreach($moredata as $items){ ?>
<li><?php echo $items; ?></li>
<?php } ?>
```

also gives me an undefined variable error for $moredata

any help on how to do this correctly in codeigniter 4 appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter uses the key of the array you're giving him to create variables name.

You should init it this way :

```
$moredata =[
   'more_data' => 'some more data',
   'even_more_data' => 'even more data',
];
// key of your array will be a variable name in your view
$data['my_var_name_in_view'] = $moredata
return view('myview',$data);
```

Then in your view you will be able to perform this :

```
<?php foreach($my_var_name_in_view as $items){ ?>
    <li><?php echo $items; ?></li>
<?php } ?>
```